# Javascript: Encapsulation of an Object When Using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How to use such functions as *setTimeout* to call member functions of objects with using of ***this*** keyword inside of called functions?

Look to my source please. I simulate this by using Javascript *closure* variables. In my case called function has argument *context* that is actually *this* for the object *o*:

```
    var Utils = 
    {
        Caller: function( context, func )
        {
            var _context = context;
            var _func = func;

            this.call = function()
            {           
                _func( _context );
            };

            return this;
        }
    };

// example of using:

function Object()
{
    this._s = "Hello, World!";
    this.startTimer = function()
    {
        var caller = new Utils.Caller( this, this._hello );
        setTimeout( caller.call, 1000 );
    };
    this._hello = function( context )
    {
        alert( context._s );
    }
}

var o = new Object();
o.startTimer();
```

Is it possible to save usual declaration of _hello() function and use keyword *this*, but not to use *context* inside?

Comment: Read up on [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)/[`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). **N.B.:** your custom `Caller.call` function will shadow the native one; be careful!

Comment: The name `Object` references the built-in `Object` constructor. You don't want to shadow it...

Comment: `return this;` inside `Caller` is not necessary since you're using it as a constructor anyways.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas 'return this; inside...' I am not sure. It seems to be a problem if you have several objects of *Caller*. Hm... May be you are right, let's test.

Comment: @s.zakharov When you call a function as a constructor (via `new`), the `this` value will be returned **by default**. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Auu3L/)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas OK, you are winner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do traditional private member hiding from classical OOP, use the following:

```
    function MyObj() {

        // setup private closure scope
        var that = this;  // keep reference to this in constructor closure scope
        var s = "Hello, World!";
        var hello = function() {
            alert(s);
        };

        // expose public methods  
        this.startTimer = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                hello();
            }, 1000);
        };
    }

    var o = new MyObj();
    o.startTimer();
```

Another approach:

```
    function MyObj() {
        var that = this;
        this._s = "Hello, World!";
        this._hello = function() {
            alert(this._s);
        };
        this.startTimer = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                hello.call(that);
            }, 1000);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I didn't understand the question, here is the code after some modifications:

```
var Utils = {
    Caller: function ( context, func ) {
        this.exec = function () {
            func.call( context );
        };
    }
};

function Obj() {
    this._s = 'Hello, World!';

    this._hello = function () {
        alert( this._s );
    }

    this.startTimer = function () {
        var caller = new Utils.Caller( this, this._hello );
        setTimeout( caller.exec, 1000 );
    };  
}

var o = new Obj();
o.startTimer();
```

Tell me what you think.

Comment: OK, thank you. I think I should use Function.apply with *Caller* and all I need is to replace *context* to *this*.